# Streamlit Doesn't start. AttributeError: Enum LabelVisibilityOptions has no value defined for name 'ValueType'

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a basic application. I have no experience working with streamlit. When I try
`streamlit run app.py`

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from streamlit.delta_generator import DeltaGenerator as _DeltaGenerator
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\delta_generator.py", line 45, in <module>
    from streamlit.elements.arrow_altair import ArrowAltairMixin
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\arrow_altair.py", line 42, in <module>
    from streamlit.elements.utils import last_index_for_melted_dataframes
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\utils.py", line 82, in <module>
    ) -> LabelVisibilityMessage.LabelVisibilityOptions.ValueType:
  File "C:\Users\joelm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\enum_type_wrapper.py", line 114, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError('Enum {} has no value defined for name {!r}'.format(
AttributeError: Enum LabelVisibilityOptions has no value defined for name 'ValueType'
```

I have installed streamlit, mysql, mysql.connector

app.py

```
import streamlit as st
from gui.login.login import login_Main

login_Main()
```

login.py inside gui/login/

```
import streamlit as st
# from user import login
# Third change in april
#from controller import *

headerSection = st.container()
mainSection = st.container()
loginSection = st.container()
logOutSection = st.container()



def login_Main():
    login()


class login():

    def show_main_page(self):
        with mainSection:
            dataFile = st.text_input("Enter your Test file name: ")
            Topics = st.text_input("Enter your Model Name: ")
            ModelVersion = st.text_input("Enter your Model Version: ")
            processingClicked = st.button ("Start Processing", key="processing")
            if processingClicked:
                st.balloons() 
    
    def LoggedOut_Clicked(self):
        st.session_state['loggedIn'] = False
        
    def show_logout_page(self):
        loginSection.empty();
        with logOutSection:
            st.button ("Log Out", key="logout", on_click=self.LoggedOut_Clicked)
        
    def LoggedIn_Clicked(self,userName, password):
        if (userName - password):
            st.session_state['loggedIn'] = True
        else:
            st.session_state['loggedIn'] = False
            st.error("Invalid user name or password")
        
    def show_login_page(self):
        with loginSection:
            if st.session_state['loggedIn'] == False:
                userName = st.text_input (label="", value="", placeholder="Enter your user name")
                password = st.text_input (label="", value="",placeholder="Enter password", type="password")
                st.button ("Login", on_click=self.LoggedIn_Clicked, args= (userName, password))

    def __init__(self):
        with headerSection:
            st.title("Streamlit Application")
            #first run will have nothing in session_state
            if 'loggedIn' not in st.session_state:
                st.session_state['loggedIn'] = False
                self.show_login_page() 
            else:
                if st.session_state['loggedIn']:
                    self.show_logout_page()    
                    self.show_main_page()  
                else:
                    self.show_login_page()
```

This is just a login window. This works on another pc but not in mine. What could be wrong.

I have
`python -V = 3.10.0`

I have tried installing python version 3.11.0. regular python code files work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revert to streamlit 1.14 for the moment, there is a problem with 1.15.0, some issues are opened : https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5742, https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5743